# I am gettingTypeCasting issue in Spinner

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I just want get the selected item from the spinner and i want to assign that variable. Here i am getting `typecasting exception`.

```
try
{
    int id1 = Integer.parseInt(sp.getSelectedItem().toString());//this line is wrong

    man.setMid(id1);
    man.setMname(name.getText().toString());
    db.updatemanager(man);
    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Now its updated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

LogCat

```
12-22 04:27:27.774: E/AndroidRuntime(1781): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 04:27:27.774: E/AndroidRuntime(1781): Process: com.draw.androidproject2, PID: 1781
12-22 04:27:27.774: E/AndroidRuntime(1781): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-22 04:27:27.774: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at com.draw.androidproject2.DialogFragment.ManagerupdateFragment$1.onClick(ManagerupdateFragment.java:57)
12-22 04:27:27.774: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
12-22 04:27:27.774: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
12-22 04:27:27.774: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-22 04:27:27.774: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-22 04:27:27.774: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-22 04:27:27.774: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-22 04:27:27.774: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 04:27:27.774: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-22 04:27:27.774: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-22 04:27:27.774: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-22 04:27:27.774: E/AndroidRuntime(1781):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-22 04:27:29.804: I/Process(1781): Sending signal. PID: 1781 SIG: 9
```

If i print the value using Log then I'am getting value.

```
Log.i(sp.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

And this is the Spinner code

```
db = new DatabaseConnection(getActivity());
         List <Manager> mgr = new ArrayList<>() ;

        mgr = db.getAll();
            adapter = new UpdateAdapter(ctx, mgr);
            sp.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: you getSelectedItem values is in number or text ?

Comment: Its a id so it will be a number.

Comment: Please share error logs because as per your code it will throw parse exception if string is not proper integer.

Comment: sp.getSelectedItem().toString() Log this and does it print an integer value??

Comment: Also show post spinner data

Comment: please post the log to get correct answer....

Comment: @MurtazaHussain I have updated with Log error.

Comment: something hasn't initialized in your code. re-check spinner initialization

Comment: @mithileshssingh  I have updated my question. Please check it

Comment: @Deep07 - what value are u getting?And also do you null pointer because of the log ?

Comment: Try using onItemSelectedListener and a switch case statement, you can debug the code easily in that case.